# Rename multiple file in directory

Tags: shell, unix

Please let me know how to formulate shell script to change name of multiple file in folder using mv command using for loop.

Comment: Did u try anything ? Can you please try out something

Comment: tried with simple for loop but its replacing whole file name as renaming content

Answer (score 0):

I'd implore you to check out the `rename(1)` command instead. It allows batch renaming of multiple files at once. For example, on the set of following files...

```
a.JPG
b.JPG
c.JPG
d.JPG
e.JPG
f.JPG
```

If I was to type `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`. It would translit all the characters in the filename to lowercase, resulting in the following list...

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
d.jpg
e.jpg
f.jpg
```

It uses expressions from 'perl', so I'd also reccoment checking that out so you can figure out how to use it.

Comment: Caution: There are two incompatible `rename` commands around. You are talking about the perl one, not the util-linux version.

Comment: Thanks Sullivan... not able to install rename package, so can us only mv command